# launching an activity that belongs to another android module

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, module, launch

I have created an android studio project "try1" with two modules. 
1. app
2. Registration

I have named the main activity as "Registration". When I click a button in app module, the activity from Registration module must be launched.

I have written the following code in the onclick method of the button, with componentName(String pkg, String cls)

Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setComponent(new              ComponentName("com.example.praveenkumar.try1","com.example.praveenkumar.try1.Registration"));
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

When I click the button, I get 'Unfortunately the app has stopped". I found
" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" in the logcat.
So I replaced(just for testing) '.Registration' in the componentName() with MainActivity of the app module in which the button itself is displayed, the code seem to work properly.

Is it a syntax error or have I mentioned a wrong path ?